# Spring boot sending emails using Thymeleaf as template - configuration does not work

Tags: java, email, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a working WebApp based on Spring Boot (newest 1.1.5.RELEASE) and Thymeleaf.
Now I would like to add functionality to send emails and use Thymeleaf as templating engine.

In pom.xml I add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Following this tutorial: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

I got complete (no XML) Java configuration like that:

```
@Configuration
public ThymeleafReplaceConfigurator {
  @Bean 
   public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSenderImpl(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        /* some properties here */

        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);

    return javaMailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver(){
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/mails/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);

        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver defaultWebTemplateResolver(){
        ServletContextTemplateResolver webTemplateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        webTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        webTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        webTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        webTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        webTemplateResolver.setOrder(2);

        return webTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(defaultWebTemplateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }
}
```

Folder and files tree is like:

```
src
  main
    resources
      templates
        login.html
        error.html
      mails
        exampleMail.html
```

But it does not work. Application starts correctly but accessing pages (which works without this configuration) causes exception like:

Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
I tried to put different prefixes into webTemplateResolver.setPrefix but without success.

Also I have noticed reported bug in earlier version of Thymeleaf causing that but looks like it was fixed and I have newer version.
**Does anyone see the mistake in this configuration?**

Comment: The problem is that you are configuring too much. Spring Boot already configures the template engine as well as the view resolver for you. Also calling `setTemplateResolver` twice with different resolvers will not do much but override the previous one. I suggest removing everything but the email configuration and the `emailTemplateResolver` everything else will be handled by Spring Boot.

Comment: Thank you very much M. Deinum, now it works like it should. Actually I did not know that autoconfigured Spring Boot will see my additional template resolver out of the box:)

Comment: Neither did I until I looked at the source for the auto configuration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main problem is that you are configuring too much.

Spring Boot already configures a `TemplateEngine` as well as a `ThymeleafViewResolver`. See the [`ThymeleafAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java) for that. If you [look at that class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java#L109) you will also notice that it will auto detect any `ITemplateResolver` instances you might have in your application and it will add it to the `SpringTemplateEngine`.

The solution is quite simple remove everything but the email configuration and the `emailTemplateResolver`. Everything else will be handled by Spring Boot.

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafEmailConfiguration {
   @Bean 
   public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSenderImpl(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        /* some properties here */

        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);

        return javaMailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver(){
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/mails/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);

        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: With Thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE there seems to be some problem in TemplateResolution using ClassLoaderTemplateResolver  if you prefix "/". 

It will work by setting emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("mails/");

Note that "/" is removed in front of "/mails/".

Comment: Exactly same problem but your solution did not worked for me! Any idea?