# Thymeleaf: second resolver for SVG in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, svg, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set up a second resolver for SVGs which use thymeleaf attributes, so it needs to be resolved by the template engine within my spring boot application. My implementation so far:

ThymeleafSvgConfig

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafSvgConfig {
    @Bean
    public FileTemplateResolver svgTemplateResolver(){
    FileTemplateResolver svgTemplateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
    svgTemplateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/svgtemplates/");
    svgTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".svg");
    svgTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("XML");
    svgTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    svgTemplateResolver.setOrder(0);

    return svgTemplateResolver;
    }

}
```

ThymeleafSvgController

```
@Controller
public class ThymeleafSvgController {
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    //.. logging etc.

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getSvg", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public void getSvg(@RequestParam(required = false) String type, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext, request.getLocale());
    templateEngine.process("test", context, response.getWriter());
    }
}
```

I read that Spring Boot searches for resolvers automatically and adds them to the engine [[s. this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610281/spring-boot-sending-emails-using-thymeleaf-as-template-configuration-does-not). So I assumed, that my Config should be enough and that via autowiring I should get the correct template engine.
But still I receive the same error in my application, when trying to call:
`templateEngine.process("test", context, response.getWriter());`
My SVG is saved in /src/main/resources/svgtemplates/test.svg

Exception:
`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "test", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

I'm not sure what I misconfigured, so I need some help with this. Is the FileTemplateResolver the correct class for this? I also tried the ClassLoaderTemplateResolver but it threw the same exception. The standard Thymeleaf Resolver from spring boot works fine, which works with the standard prefix: "classpath:/templates/". So considering that 'templates' and 'svgtemplates' lie in the same folder, my prefix should be correct so far, shouldn't it?
Maybe someone else sees the flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the FileTemplateResolver can't cope with the 'classpath:' notation. After providing the complete file path, the resolver works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` with Spring Boot which does support the `classpath:` notation:

```
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver svgTemplateResolver()
{
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/svg");
    resolver.setSuffix(".svg");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("XML");

    return resolver;
}
```

You may also want to set `spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order = 0` in you application configuration to prioritise the default resolver (typically used for the HTML templates).